# Getting syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I get an error message

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'r = row_number() over (partition by ACell order by ACell desc)'

in Microsoft Access; I don't know why, but it works in Microsoft SQL Server.

My query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select *, r = row_number() over (partition by ACell order by ACell 
    desc) 
    from cellTB) a 
where 
    r <= 5;
```

Please could anyone help me?

Example Data: cellTB

```
=================
ACell  |   RNC
=================
1      |   1
-----------------
1      |   2
-----------------
1      |   3
-----------------
1      |   4 
-----------------
1      |   5
-----------------
1      |   6
-----------------
2      |   1
-----------------
2      |   2
-----------------
2      |   3
-----------------
2      |   4
-----------------
2      |   5
-----------------
2      |   6
```

I want to select just top 5 from duplicate ACell in MC Access.

Comment: Is this a pass-through query sent to SQL Server? If not, the syntax isn't correct, as Access doesn't support window functions

Comment: I don't know how to user these command 'r = row_number() over (partition by ACell order by ACell desc)' in Access.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output. Do you need an Access query object?

Comment: @June7 I have already input the example data and output that I want from this query.

Answer (score 1):

You code is *T-SQL*. For *Access SQL* you can, for example, use my *RowNumber* function as previously posted several times:

[Sequential row numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778136/add-autoincrement-to-existing-query-not-table-in-ms-access-2016/52779515#52779515)

Answer (score 1):

MS Access doesn't support `row_number()` (just one of many reasons to switch to another database).  One method to do what you want uses a correlated subquery:

```
select c.* 
from cellTB as c
where (select count(*)
       from cellTb as c2
       where c2.Acell = c.Acell and
             c2.id <= c.id  -- this is the primary key column
      ) <= 5;
```

This assumes that your table has a primary key, which is called `id` in this example.